# Database ERROR:You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing php development, and I got an error like this

> Database ERROR:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND acid_event.sid IN(7, 8, 9, 20, 23, 24)' at line 3

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip_src FROM acid_event
               WHERE timestamp >='2015-09-08 00:00:00' AND timestamp <='2015-09-08 23:59:59'
                AND acid_event.analyzed='N' AND (signature=2176) OR signature=70 OR signature=424 OR signature=927 OR signature=981 OR signature=19 OR signature=928 OR signature=1414 OR signature=289) AND acid_event.sid IN(7, 8, 9, 20, 23, 24)
```

Comment: but I don't know how to change the code, thanks

Comment: why don't you use IN for signature too?

Comment: It looks like you are closing your parenthesis too early `AND (signature=2176) OR signature=70 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more closing brackets than opening brackets in your final SQL. It is not clear from the partial code you provided why this is happening.

I would suggest however to simplify the SQL you build, so that it produces something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip_src FROM acid_event
WHERE timestamp >='2015-09-08 00:00:00' AND timestamp <='2015-09-08 23:59:59'
AND acid_event.analyzed='N' 
AND signature IN (2176, 70, 424, 927, 981, 19, 928, 1414, 289)
AND acid_event.sid IN(7, 8, 9, 20, 23, 24)
```

This could be done with this simpler code, that first collects the values in an array *$list* and than converts that to the `signature IN (...)` syntax:

```
if ( $isman ) {
    $list = array();
    for ( $i=1;$i<=$nummansigs;$i++) {
        // get the sig_ids for the first manadatory signature
        $sql = "SELECT sig_id FROM signature WHERE sig_sid=".$sigsid[$i];
        $idresult = $db->acidExecute($sql);
        while ( $idrow = $idresult->acidFetchRow() ) {
            $list[] = $idrow[0];
        }
        $idresult->acidFreeRows();
    }
    $mansig = "";
    if (count($list)) {
        $mansig = " AND signature IN (" . implode(",", $list) . ") ";
    }
    $notmansig = str_replace(" IN ", " NOT IN ", $mansig);
}
```

The code could also be improved to not do a new query in each for-loop iteration, but I will leave that optimisation to you. The principle would be the same: try to do one query with a `sig_sid IN (...list of sids...)` condition, so you get all the necessary values in one go.

Answer (score 4):

If we space it out a bit, we can easily see the error

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip_src FROM acid_event
    WHERE timestamp >='2015-09-08 00:00:00' AND timestamp <='2015-09-08 23:59:59'
        AND acid_event.analyzed='N' 
        AND (signature=2176) <----- Remove this bracket as it closes to early
        OR signature=70 
        OR signature=424 
        OR signature=927 
        OR signature=981 
        OR signature=19 
        OR signature=928 
        OR signature=1414 
        OR signature=289) 
        AND acid_event.sid IN(7, 8, 9, 20, 23, 24)
```

Delete that bracket ;)

Just read over your code again and the easiest way is to use another IN statement again, so you would want the query to look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip_src FROM acid_event
    WHERE timestamp >='2015-09-08 00:00:00' AND timestamp <='2015-09-08 23:59:59'
        AND acid_event.analyzed='N' 
        AND signature IN(2176, 70, 424, 927, 981, 19, 928, 1414, 289)
        AND acid_event.sid IN(7, 8, 9, 20, 23, 24)
```

You could do the following:

```
    for ( $i=1;$i<=$nummansigs;$i++) 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT sig_id FROM signature WHERE sig_sid=".$sigsid[$i];
        $idresult = $db->acidExecute($sql);
        $mansig = "IN ("
        while ( $idrow = $idresult->acidFetchRow() )
        {

          $mansig = $mansig . "{$idrow[0]}, ";

         }
         $idresult->acidFreeRows();
    }
    $mansig = trim($mansig, ", ")
     $mansig = $mansig.")";
```

Although, you haven't posted all of your code so I have no idea how it actually works.

Comment: Was barely going to post that.

Comment: Instead of removing that closing paren, remove the one above. Then all the `OR` are within the parens.

Comment: However the code does not explain why there was a closing bracket inserted right after 2176.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Ahh, nice spotting.

Comment: @trincot That's nice, but he's posted small snippets of his code which mean absolutely nothing to us

Comment: @Matt thank you Matt. I tried your code, but its not working. I really want to post more code here, but its really a big project. Thank you again. Your code really inspired me.

Answer (score -1):

Your query has unopened ')' at signature=289). Either remove ')' or add opening '('